# Alasql is not working in angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, xls, alasql

I am referring for this link to work with alasql in angularjs http://plnkr.co/edit/2UKA8yPl9Uiarr2uSwEd?p=preview. But even though i change the alasql sources it still throws Reference error:alasql is not defined in the controller.What else should i change to make it work?

```
 $scope.exportData = function () {
    alasql('SELECT * INTO XLS("test.xls",?) FROM ?',[mystyle,$scope.items]);
};
```

Comment: Have you added `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alasql/0.4.2/alasql.min.js"></script>` ? Share your plunkr thats not working

Comment: Hi Shashank i am using this alasql source <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alasql/0.3/alasql.min.js"></script>.